# custom decorator for class viewsets

Tags: python, django, python-decorators

I have a view set like this

```
class NeProjectsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):

   def list(self, request,org_unique_id):
       ''' something '''

   def create(self, request,org_unique_id):
       ''' something '''

   def retrieve(self):
       ''' something '''

   def update(self, request, pk):
       ''' something '''

   def partial_update(self, request):
       ''' something '''

   def destroy(self, request):
       ''' something '''
```

and i've a method like this

```
def check_session(self,request):
    current_datetime = datetime.now()
    if ('last_login' in request.session):
        last = (current_datetime - datetime.strptime(request.session['last_login'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")).seconds
        if last > base.SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT:
            del request.session['token']
            raise ValueError('Session Expired')
    else:
        request.session['last_login'] = str(current_datetime)
    return (request.session['token'] == request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])
```

to validate session for every request, for that i need to call this method before every method in the viewset. I read somewhere writing custom decorator is better way, so how to implement custom decorator for my view set to check session for request

Comment: Most likely in this case it will be more convenient to  [add custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware)

Comment: i want to validate session for particular apis only, not for every api, if we can do that with middleware can you provide the code how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming you are using DRF.*

I think you are going in wrong direction. If this is part of your permission layer you should just add custom permission class to your viewset

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class ValidateSession(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Validate session expiration
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        current_datetime = datetime.now()
        if ('last_login' in request.session):
            last = (current_datetime - datetime.strptime(request.session['last_login'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")).seconds
            if last > base.SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT:
                del request.session['token']
                return False
        else:
            request.session['last_login'] = str(current_datetime)
        return (request.session['token'] == request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])
```

And then add it like this

```
class NeProjectsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    permission_classes = (ValidateSession,)
    ...
```

*Assuming you're using plain django*

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import AccessMixin

class ValidateSessionMixin(AccessMixin):
    """
    Validate session
    """
    def has_permission(self):
        current_datetime = datetime.now()
        request = self.request
        if ('last_login' in request.session):
            last = (current_datetime - datetime.strptime(request.session['last_login'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")).seconds
            if last > base.SESSION_IDLE_TIMEOUT:
                del request.session['token']
                return True
        else:
            request.session['last_login'] = str(current_datetime)
        return (request.session['token'] == request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.has_permission():
            return self.handle_no_permission()
        return super(ValidateSessionMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

And apply this mixin like this

```
class NeProjectsViewSet(ValidateSessionMixin, viewsets.ViewSet):
    ...
```

Comment: I see the request is in the has_permission function. If I want to apply different permissions for read or write, would I just check the request to see if it is GET or PUT? I don't see a clear distinction between validating read or write on different rules (other than allow all read, which I clearly do not want, unless I'm misreading that documentation link).

Comment: @KennyOstrom do you want this in drf or django?

Comment: It's a django app with rest_framework.viewsets.ViewSet and some custom rules about who can see which content, and I'm adding a write interface (implementing the viewset's create) that has to check an additional permission on request.user

Comment: @KennyOstrom I suggest creating a separate question for this